# pyspark only uses half memory ec2-spark

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, pyspark

I am playing around with Spark using the supplied spark-ec2:

```
./spark-ec2 \
--key-pair=pems \
--identity-file=/path/pems.pem \
--region=eu-west-1 \
-s 8 \
--instance-type c3.xlarge \
launch my-spark-cluster
```

After install I ssh into the master node after it has fully installed and then I start pyspark.

```
$ /root/spark/bin/pyspark --executor-memory 2G
```

I specify (at least I think) that each executor (machine) gets 2GB of memory. When I browse the console at `<masternode>:4040` then I see that something didn't go right.

[image]

When I enter other preferences I get a similar result.

```
$ /root/spark/bin/pyspark --executor-memory 1G
```

[image]

The confusing part for me is that I specified `c3.xlarge` machines and these have ~7.5 Gb of memory so this shouldn't be an issue with memory shortage. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory shown here is memory allocated for caching
It is defined by `spark.storage.memoryFraction` config and its default value is `.6`

Comment: is it possible to raise it? considering that i want to load data from s3 *once* for the remainder of the analysis this seems like something id like to raise manually.

Comment: yes you can increase it. while starting executor --config spark.storage.memoryFraction 0.8, please note that this should not be larger than the "old" generation of objects in the JVM, which by default is given 0.6 of the heap.

Comment: note for future readers. you can use this command: ```/root/spark/bin/pyspark --conf spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.75```